# how to get a layout on click of imageview?

Tags: java, android, layout, onclick, imageview

[image]

Hello.. I have a layout in which I have `ImageView` and `EditText` view. I want to add a different layout on click of `ImageView` of arrow.

[image]

It should look like this after click event of `ImageView`. How can I get this??
Pleas help...

Comment: Show us the code you wrote.

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For perfect answer please add your xml file and java file source code.

**Example**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout linear1,linear2;
    ImageView imgArrow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        linear1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
        linear2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear2);
        imgArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgArrow);

        linear1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(linear2.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                    linear2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imgArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
                }else{
                    linear2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imgArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnClick"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Additional Contact" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgArrow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:src="@drawable/down" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User Name here" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Phone number here" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Click Here" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

***Here down and up is image file for arrow.
so put that both arrow file in drawable folder.***

[image]
[image]

Comment: @user3623979 If my answer is helpful for you then accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set an `OnClickListener` to the ImageView, which contains the arrow. Then assign a method, which handles the click and produces your different layout