# android-setting layout below programmatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, whitespace

[image]

I have a layout where I have a textView called Facilities and below it are its details.The details are embedded within a linearlayout1.Below it is another linearlayout2.When I click on a button, the visisbility of the linearlayout1 will be gone, but the problem is it leaves a whitespace.I want the layout below the linearlayout1 to occupy the whitespace.Is there a way to programmatically set the linearlayout2 below linearlayout1 when the button is clicked.

mascotlayot.xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Facilities"
                android:textColor="#37474F"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
                android:id="@+id/up"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

                />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linear1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image24"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"

                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image24"
                    android:text="Ayurveda therapies"

                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image67"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image24"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text32"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text3"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image67"
                    android:text="Wi-fi facility"

                    android:textColor="#000000">

                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image68"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image67"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text33"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text32"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image67"
                    android:text="Coffee Shop"

                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image69"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image68"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text34"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text33"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image69"
                    android:text="Restaurant"

                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image70"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image69"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text35"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text34"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image70"
                    android:text="Banquet and Conference halls"

                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image71"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image70"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text36"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text35"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image71"
                    android:text="Bar"

                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image72"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image71"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text37"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text36"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image72"
                    android:text="Swimming Pool"

                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image73"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image72"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text38"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text37"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image73"
                    android:text="Ayurvedic Centres"

                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image74"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image73"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text39"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text38"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image74"
                    android:text="Health Club"


                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image75"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image74"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text40"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text39"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image73"
                    android:text="Travel Assistance"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image76"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image75"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text41"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text40"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image76"
                    android:text="Car Hire"

                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image77"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image76"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text42"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text41"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image77"
                    android:text="Laundry"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image78"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image77"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text43"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text42"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image78"
                    android:text="Doctor-on-call"

                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image79"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image78"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text44"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text43"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image79"
                    android:text="Currency Exchange"

                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linear2"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="Attractions"
                android:textColor="#37474F"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image16"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text20"
                    android:background="#90000000"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text20"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text19"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Kerala Legislature Complex"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image17"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text19"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text21"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text20"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Science and Technology Museum Complex"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image18"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image17"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="#90000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text22"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text21"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Priyadarshini Planetarium"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

MascotFragment.java:

```
 linear=(LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linear2);
             linear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

             imageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.up);
             linear3=(LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linear3);


    int i=1;
     imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     if ((i % 2)!=0) {

                         imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float));
                         linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                     }
                     else{

                         imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float));
                         linear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                         if(i==10){
                             i=0;
                         }
                     }
                     i++;

                 }
             });
```

Comment: Make the `linearlayout1` to invisible, not gone.

Comment: linear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  I have already set it to invisible

Comment: Look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774726/how-to-get-a-layout-on-click-of-imageview/33774984#33774984 .  This will help you.

Comment: @jobin: show ur xml file

Comment: @jobin Post your XML, java code.

Comment: I have included the xml and java code

Comment: Use `GONE` instead of `INVISIBLE`.

Comment: @chirag Thank you.Now the problem is GONE..

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Change View.INVISIBLE to View.GONE like this:

```
linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

VIEW.INVISIBLE made view invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
VIEW.GONE doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using **fragments**. Here's a good resource on it 
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments#fragment-with-arguments